# Jest "Matcher error: expected value must be a function"

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs, httpexception

I'm using NestJS with Jest and I get this error:

> Matcher error: expected value must be a function

... when run following unit test.

I have set invalid email in `mockBody`. Did I missed anything here?

**app.service.ts**

```js
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(private emailService: EmailService) {}

  async registerUserInquiry(user: UserDto): Promise<{ email: string }> {
    try {
      await sendEmail(user);
    } catch (error) {
      throw new HttpException('Something went wrong!', HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
    return {
      email: user.email,
    };
  }
}
```

**app.service.spec.ts**

```js
describe("registerUser()", () => {
  it("Should throw bad request error when passing invalid data", async () => {
    const mockBody: UserDto = {
      name: "John Doe",
      message: "Example inquiry message",
      email: "@example",
      mobile: "+60121234567",
    };

    expect(async () => await service.registerUserInquiry(mockBody)).toThrow(
      new HttpException("Something went wrong!", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    );
  });
});
```

**email.config.ts**

```js
export const sendEmail = async (user: User) => {
  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    ... // service & auth
  });

  const options = {
   ... // email info
  };

  await transporter.sendMail(options, function (error, info) {
    try {
      console.info(error);
      return info;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      throw error;
    }
  });
};
```

**Error:**

[image]

Comment: `expect(response).toThrowError();` makes no sense because: 1. you need to pass a function to defer execution so the error can be caught (see https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tothrowerror); but also 2. if it did error you'd never reach that line - it's a promise, `await`ing it means the error ends up in the `catch` block. I'd strongly recommend looking at the options in https://jestjs.io/docs/tutorial-async.

Comment: `expect(() => {service.register(mockBody);}).toThrow(new HttpException('Something went wrong!', HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST));`
can u please provide some example ?

Comment: That _doesn't_ throw an error, it returns a promise that rejects.

Comment: Actually because you included the braces it returns undefined, and ignores the promise that rejects, causing an unhandled promise error.

Comment: `expect(received).toThrow(expected)
Expected message: "Something went wrong!"
Received function did not throw`
im getting this error now.

`expect(async () => await service.registerUserInquiry(mockBody)).toThrow(new HttpException('Something went wrong!', HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);`

Comment: Please [edit] the question to give a [mre].

Comment: (But again, async function return promises. They don't throw errors.)

Comment: 1. That's not a MRE, 2. you haven't updated the error, and 3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71740269/jest-matcher-error-expected-value-must-be-a-function#comment126783069_71740269. Read the linked docs, which explain several methods for testing promises.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243608/discussion-between-johnny-and-jonrsharpe).

Answer (score 3):

Instead of this

```js
expect(async () => await service.registerUserInquiry(mockBody)).toThrow(
  new HttpException("Something went wrong!", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
);
```

Try this one

```js
await expect(service.registerUserInquiry(mockBody)).rejects.toThrowError(...)
```

Your function is a promise which means it is not throwing an error but instead it rejects.

Comment: `expect(received).rejects.toThrowError()
Received promise resolved instead of rejected
Resolved to value: {"email": "@example"}`
received this error now

Comment: @Johnny then you presumably haven't set up the test such they it _does_ reject, without a MRE it's hard to say, but the test failure is now about the behaviour of your code not that the assertion itself is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```js
try {
    await service.registerUserInquiry(mockBody)
} catch(err) {
expect(err).toBeInstanceOf(BAD_REQUEST);
expect(err.message).toEqual{'Something went wrong!'}
}
```